# position a button inside a panel in bottom center (asp.net)

Tags: css, button, panel, center

i read about centering (bottom-center) a button inside a div , which is like centering a button inside a panel.
i succeeded in doing that by adding this to the CSS of the button:

```
 position:absolute; 
  margin-left:50%;
  margin-right:50%;
  bottom:  5px;
```

and the panel css property is:

```
position:relative;
```

The problem is that it centers the **left side of the button**, so the button itself with his whole width is not centered.

How do i center the center of the button, so it will look like the button is really centered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example write like this if you have `position absolute`:

```
button{
   position:absolute; 
   margin-left:-100px;
   left:50%;
   width:200px;
   bottom:5px;
}
```

*Note:* give `margin-left` `half` of the `width` of the `button`

Comment: i didn't ,it was someone else. you have the right answer but without the minus in the "left:-50%". it is supposed to be left:50%. so thank you :). i can't mark the V for the right answer because people will copy paste it without reading my comment and get it wrong...., so can you edit it?

Comment: @Rodniko; it's a typo mistake :)

Comment: How would it be if you dont know the width in px, because you want to use a percentage of the container div, for example button must take 80% of the width.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
margin-left:50%;
margin-right:50%;
```

try

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: Doesn't work , the button appears at the bottom left corner. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you could post your actual code or give us a link to the test site we might be able to help you more.

Comment: You could also try:
text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
margin : 0 auto;
```

instead of `margin-left` and `margin-right`

It's mean is 0 px margin for top and bottom (you can set it too!!) , and auto margin for left and right. It will center, object.

And remove `position : absulote;`

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/wu7RL/)

Comment: try adding `text-align:center;` to your panel.